# Rails not using Postgres user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm using Rails 3.0 and PostgreSQL 8.4 on Ubuntu 10.10 and Ruby 1.9.2p136 with the pg gem. When I run `rake db:migrate`, I get the error `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my_os_user_account"`, when I actually expected it to log in to the database as my_db_username specified in database.yml.

I have md5 authentication configured in pg_hba.conf for both Unix socket and IP connections and I can log in using `psql` on the command line. I have also tried setting the authentication to trust. `psql` then allows me to log in without entering a password, but Rails then gives `FATAL:  role "my_os_user_account" does not exist`.

Here's database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: my_project_dev
  user: my_db_username
  password: my_password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

with additional near-identical entries for test and production.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct key for `username` is, in fact, `username` and not `user`. Easy mistake, easy fix.

Comment: I love it when it's easy! I don't know why I didn't spot that.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. However, my issue was brackets around the actual username and passowrd  in database.yml like this "[admin]... [passowrd]", this works for ruby 1.8.7, but not newer versions. Spent an entire aggravating day on this. I realized that might be it after reading this article. (shrug) Hope this helps someone else.